# Pass JSON data in Django context

Tags: javascript, json, django

Normally, if I want to return JSON data from a Django view, I can use a [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) like so:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def my_view(request):
    return JsonResponse({'my_key': 'my_value'})
```

That data is sent to the frontend as a JavaScript object that I can immediately use.

I'd like that same ease of use added to the context of a view, like so:

```
class WebsiteView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['my_var'] = {'my_key': 'my_value'}
        return context
```

However, rendering the template with `{{ my_var }}` gives:

```
{&quot;my_key&quot;: &quot;my_value&quot;}
```

Ultimately, what I want is for `{{ my_var }}` to return the plain string rather than the HTML encoded version:

```
{"my_key": "my_value"}
```

This way, I can easily load it into a JavaScript object with `JSON.parse('{{ my_var }}')`.

I know that one way to achieve this is by [manually unescaping the HTML entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript), but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Django template documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#how-to-turn-it-off) you should be able to do use the `|safe` filter in your template:

`{{ my_var|safe }}`

This should instruct the Django template engine to render the data verbatim.

Comment: Perfect! Could have sworn I tried that before without any success... ah well. Thanks!